# Python and Active Directory (modules pyad, flask_ldap, active_directory, python_ldap, etc.)

Tags: python, flask, active-directory

Trying to investigate using Python instead of a compiled language to support users with "web applications", etc.  So at this point, I'm getting the various aspects of "what we do" and trying basic things out to find out if they work.

I'm sure this will probably result in a "not specific enough", or something similar, BUT there are so many problems/issues with all the packages I've tried to install for Python and Active Directory, it makes me wonder if these are being heavily used, and if not - what should be?

We operate in an mixed Windows/Linux environment,  Windows servers are 2012/2012R2/2016, Linux boxes are generally RHEL 7 level (couple of older RHEL5 boxes that will be updated).  PCs are all 64bit, Windows 10

Need the following capabilities

- Host the flask content on either Windows or Linux server
- Get the current AD account login from the client (are they logged into AD, and what account?)
- From that current account - get the groups that the account is a member of
- something still supported, and not "umpteen" years old...

I've "looked" into using/installing (on Windows ONLY at this time...):

1. active_directory (fails because of print syntax errors in the installation of pypiwin32 apparently)
2. pyad (fails due to above issue in pypiwin32)
3. python_ldap (fails because VStudio 14.0 is required?!  I don't know of a VS version 14 - and this is "Windows unique")
4. flask_ldap (requires python_ldap which fails)
5. couple of others with same problems, etc.

Why do several of these REQUIRE a Win32 component (pypiwin32), especially if you operate in a "64bit only" environment?  I'm also assuming the pypiwin32 "print" issue is a change between python 2 and 3 (i.e. "print 'something'" vs. "print('something')"???

Being as nothing I can find for python and active directory will install, I'm not sure where to turn.  As I said, I'm investigating at this point.

Comment: Forgot to mention - I'm using Python 3.8

Comment: `Win32` refers to the Application Programming Interface (API) used to program traditional Windows Desktop applications for 32 and 64-bit Windows.

Comment: `pypiwin32` was an unofficial way to install the `pywin32` package via pip. It is outdated and no longer necessary. pywin32's `win32com.adsi` interface can be used to get all groups a user is member of.

Comment: Ok - but it certainly appears that pywin32 is Windows only.  I'd like something cross-platform - Linux and Windows, which would seem to require something LDAP.  Is there no cross-platform (Linux/Windows) module that provides Active Directory queries?

Answer (score 0):

win32 appears to be the only officially supported version, but there are alternative 64bit builds available.
e.g. https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Ok - but why don't the "official" modules support both 32/64bit and find out what you're on - ask you, etc.?  (Yes, I know I'm asking a question for the package maintainer - but in all this time the only solution is to "jack around" finding packages/libraries from other sources and come up with some other method to install?)

Answer (score 0):

The **ms_active_directory** module is doing nearly everything a SysAdmin needs to do with Active Directory.

The module: https://pypi.org/project/ms-active-directory/

The documentation: https://ms-active-directory.readthedocs.io/

The Github project: https://github.com/zorn96/ms_active_directory/